# Mysqli query not working with temporary table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Can someone explain why this query that work on mysql don't work on mysqli?

```
$queryCreateTemp = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS receita_anual_temp AS (SELECT servmensal_empresa_id AS receita_anual_temp_empresa_id, SUM(servmensal_receita) AS receita_anual_temp_receita_anual FROM servmensal GROUP BY servmensal_empresa_id)";

$mysqli->query($queryCreateTemp);
```

Thanks in advance!

The error was:

```
Access denied for user 'user'@'%' to database 'database'
```

Thanks Ar7proface.

Comment: Luck you. I cannot flag your question today due to limit of flagging be reached. This is not kind of question here that we can answer to you. You need to tell us what is your specific problem, what have you tried, what result you expect.

Comment: Since we're not psychic, can you post an error? A result code? Anything that might help diagnose this? "Does not work" is not a useful way of describing a problem.

Comment: Sorry, It's the first time I'm posting here. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$ql="CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS receita_anual_temp AS (SELECT servmensal_empresa_id AS receita_anual_temp_empresa_id, SUM(servmensal_receita) AS receita_anual_temp_receita_anual FROM servmensal GROUP BY servmensal_empresa_id)";
if ($mysqli->query($ql) === TRUE) {
    printf("right <br>");
}else{
    printf("fail <br>");
} 
?>
result=right;
```

Remember it is a temporary table -- at the end of the query that table is deleted.

Comment: `x === TRUE` is pretty crazy redundant here.

Comment: Thanks with that I found the error. The user had no right to create a temporary table.

Comment: WHAT? Why did you accepted this answer since it was user's privileges?

Comment: The tmp table goes away when the _connection_ ends.